# Ember js observer issue

Tags: ember.js, radio-button, click, observers

When clicked the ember radio, observing the clicked radio using below function named bindingChanged. But as soon as radio button is clicked the value is n't getting observed and hence not hitting bindingChanged method. This used to work fine with ember 0.9.8 version. It's not working with latest ember version. Any idea why observer not working as expected?

```
//valueBinding snippet
App.showSampleController = Ember.Object.create({
    content : App.CreateSampleModel.create()
});

App.CreateSampleModel= Ember.Object.extend({
    id :''
});

//View Template -->
App.sampleView = Em.View.extend({
    click:function(){
        App.showSampleController.set('content',App.CreateSampleModel.create({id:1})); 
    }
});
```

Handle bar snippet:

```
{{ view Ember.RadioButton group="default" name="sampleRadio"  option=content.id valueBinding="App.showSampleController.content.id" }}
```

Below is radio button code

```
Ember.RadioButton = Ember.View.extend({
    title: null,
    checked: false,
    group: "radio_button",
    disabled: false,
    customId:"open",

    classNames: ['ember-radio-button'],

    defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<input type="radio" {{ bindAttr disabled="disabled" name="group" value="option" checked="checked" id="customId" }} />{{title}}'),

    bindingChanged: function(){
        if(this.get("option") == get(this, 'value')){
            this.set("checked", true);
            //invoking click when ember radio is accessed/checked/clicked!!
            this.$('input:radio').click();
        }
    }.observes("value"),

    change: function() {
        Ember.run.once(this, this._updateElementValue);
    },

    _updateElementValue: function() {
        var input = this.$('input:radio');
        set(this, 'value', input.attr('value'));
    }
});
```

Here is a  [original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craig/MBmUs/2/) and below is another fiddle and you can see the bug in below fiddle. The major difference is it has latest ember and it's completely breaking [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBmUs/193/)

Answer (score 1):

Problem with view context in templates. You should have your template like

```
<label><input type="radio" {{ bindAttr disabled="view.disabled" name="view.group" value="view.option" checked="view.checked"}} />{{view.title}}</label>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MBmUs/194/) is working version. [Refer](http://emberjs.com/blog/2012/08/03/ember-1-0-prerelease/) here